# Create date without the UTC offset

Tags: php

If I have a date like `12:00:00 +0800`, is there a way I can create a date or timestamp without the `+0800`? For my use case, I don't need the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

For more information, [**read**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) the docs.

Alternatively, you can use the [**DateTime Class**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) functions.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me.  I basically want 12:00:00.  But when I do strtotime with the current time, it takes the offset into account unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Crystal Did you read the docs? You might need `h:i:s` instead of `Y-m-d`.